# Playwright w/ Specflow and NUnit: Parallel execution only on some tests

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, nunit, playwright, specflow

I want to run some tests on parallel and some tests not on parallel. When I use [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)], all of the tests are running on parallel even if I use [NonParallelizable]

Is there a way to set a group of tests to run on separately on parallel?

Comment: What's missing in your question is an example of how you use [NonParallelizable] and where you put it in your code. You should edit the question to add that info rather than answering in a comment.

Comment: I am using playwright with specflow so I have gherkin feature files. I am trying to add the [NonParallelizable] tag on hooks.